# How to find out if I still have Python 2.7 on Mac? Does installing Python 3.3 also uninstall the older package?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

Could there possibly be hidden files that I would need to find. Or do I have to re-install Python 2.7 if I want to work with it?

Thanks

Comment: No, Mac comes with 2.7 pre-installed and you should **not** uninstall it. Installing 3.3 is *in addition*, and won't replace the 2.7 installation.

Comment: `which -a python` will show all python installs

Comment: @MartijnPieters The following is an image of all the files in my bin folder and hence my initial question. I don't remember uninstalling Python 2.7 but I can't see any files pertaining to it.http://imgur.com/uBO6Liw

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for your response and I found out the files and attached the respective image to the comment above. Does this mean I must have accidentally uninstalled 2.7

Comment: @YashChitneni: does `ls /usr/bin/python` produce anything?

Comment: @MartijnPieters when I type that in terminal, I only get /usr/bin/python as a response which I searched for and have all the files regarding 3.* but as Yogeesh mentioned in his answer, I looked up the version and it states the version I am using is 2.7.5.

Comment: does `/usr/bin/python` start a python 2 shell?

Comment: @YashChitneni: yes, because `ls /usr/bin/python` looks for **just** that file. It means the system python was not uninstalled.

Comment: On a related note when working with multiple versions of python [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) is a lifesaver. Let's you set up different environments with all the packages you need without affecting your system install. You can also build the python versions you want from source and use them this way.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, it does. I made a mistake earlier. I looked up /usr/local/bin rather than /usr/bin/python and this showed me the files for Python 3.3. Thank You for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python installations on OS X generally go in separately and don't uninstall each other. Also, the convention is still for the executable `python` to refer to 2 and `python3` to refer to 3, so they don't even really overlap.

Common locations you might have python include

- `/usr/bin/python` (the system installed one, probably an osx specific 2.7.5)
- `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/...`  This is where the ones you install from Python.org go, separately for each version.
- Your homebrew directory if you are using that

Which one runs when you type `python` (or `python3`) depends on your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

`python --version` - will give you the version of the currently used python in environment variable `PATH`.

Nothing gets uninstalled. You have to just adjust the `PATH` variable according what you will be using.

Comment: Yogeesh, thanks for your response. It states that the current python that I am using is as a matter of fact Python 2.7.5 but based on the following image: http://imgur.com/uBO6Liw. It doesn't seem like I have any files related to it. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Just try to open python console and try importing some modules, some default modules like `import os`. And try out `locate python` in terminal - that will list out all python related files present in the system. This will give a clear picture and will help you get rid of your confusion.